# How to join 3 tables where each has the key to the next in line

Tags: mysql

Imagine the following scenario:

There are 3 tables A, B and C.

- Table A has no knowledge of either table B and table C.
- Table B has a foreign key to table A.
- Table C has foreign key to table B.

In table B as well as in table C there can be multiple items sharing the same foreign key value.

As you can see, the items from C are indirectly referenced to A *through* B.

What I want is to get all entries from A that are referenced in C but without any information from B or C in my result tables and without duplicates.

Is this even possible?

I have tried this like so but have no idea if it is correct:

```
select tableA.*
from tableA, 

    (select distinct tableB.AId as Aid
    from tableB left join tableC on tableC.BId = tableB.id
    group by tableB.id)

as temp
where tableA.id = temp.Aid
```

Comment: it would be great if you provide some sample data for table A,B,C and based on that sample data a output you are expecting.

Comment: Your attempt mixes , and inner join syntax.  In current (1994+) SQL you really should not be using commas.  Take a look at https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ to help understand joins.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It really helped understanding joins. I have learned the comma usage in the early beginning of my sql usage. (Which was sparse to begin with). Do you have input why commas are not used anymore?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understand it correctly, but you can try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `A`.`id`, `A`.`value1`, `A`.`value2`  FROM `A`
INNER JOIN `B` ON `B`.`id-a` = `A`.`id`
INNER JOIN `C` ON `C`.`id-b` = `B`.`id`
```

It returns all values from table A if there is a key on Table C which is linked to Table B with corresponding foreign key on table A

Comment: This looks to be a good way of doing this.The distinct is needed because carnality between C-B and B-A could cause records in A to repeat. Either a group by or distinct would be needed and since no aggregation is being used, distinct makes more sense.

Comment: I would add that you can use `SELECT \`A\`.*` to select all columns from Table A, no need to manually enter all columns.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to Masoud's good response would be to use an `exists` though a correlated subquery.

The below subquery joins B to C in a correlated fashion (notice the B.IDA to A.ID and A is outside the subquery).

If we assume good database design, then A will not have duplicate records, thus we can omit a distinct here since we are not joining A to the other tables.  Instead we are simply checking for the existence of an "A" record in the B table which must have a record in the C table due to the inner join.  This has two advantages for performance

1. It doesn't have to join all the records together which would then
   necessitate a distinct; thus you don't have the performance hit on
   the distinct.
2. It can early escape.  once a key value of A is found in the
   subquery (B to C join) , it can stop looking and thus don't have to join all of B to all of A.

We select "1" in the subquery as we don't care what we select as the value will not be used anywhere.  We're just using the coloration of A to (B JOIN C) to determine what in A to display.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
             FROM C
             INNER JOIN B
               on C.IDB = B.ID)
              AND B.IDA = A.ID)
```

Taking what you tried and reviewing it:

```
select tableA.*
from tableA, 

    (select distinct tableB.AId as Aid
    from tableB left join tableC on tableC.BId = tableB.id
    group by tableB.id)

as temp
where tableA.id = temp.Aid
```

Starting with the "FROM"

You have tableA, (subquery) temp.  This is a CROSS JOIN meaning all records from A will be joined to ALL records of (B JOIN C) so if you have 1000 records in A and 1000 records in the temp result then you'd be telling the database engine to generate 1000*1000 records in your result set; which then gets filtered to only include records matching in temp and A.  The engine may be smart enough to avoid the cross join and optimize the query, but I find it confusing to maintain.  So I would rewrite as

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN  (SELECT distinct tableB.AId as Aid
             FROM tableB left join tableC on tableC.BId = tableB.id
             GROUP BY tableB.id)    as temp
        ON tableA.id = temp.Aid
```

Looking at the subquery (temp)

We don't need a group by as we are not aggregating.  The distinct does bring us down to 1 record but at a cost to execution time.

So I would re-write as this:

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN  (SELECT distinct tableB.AId as Aid
             FROM tableB 
             LEFT JOIN tableC 
               on tableC.BId = tableB.id) as temp
        ON tableA.id = temp.Aid
```

Then looking at the whole, if we change the outer query join to temp and make it an exists... using coloration we don't have the performance hit of the join, nor the distinct. and I'd switch the left join to an inner as we only want records in C and B so we'd have null in B if we left it as a "LEFT JOIN" which serve no purpose for us.

This gets me to the answer I initially provided.

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM tableB 
             INNER JOIN tableC 
               on tableC.BId = tableB.id
              AND tableB.AID = A.ID) as temp
```

Comment: thanks for the answers! I will need to think both of them through.